# How to build a query to list all stories using ScriptRunner in JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

I have a query that returns the list of all epics

`"Parent Link" = ABCD-28089 AND "Requested Version" = "Release 3.3.0" ORDER BY key ASC`

this in JIRA evaluates correctly and returns the list of all epics.

Now I want to create another query using the ScriptRunner which needs to flatten and return all the stories under each of the epics returned by the above list

`issueFunction in issuesInEpics("Parent Link" = ABCD-28089 AND "Requested Version" = "Release 3.3.0" ORDER BY key ASC)`

But this complains with something like
`Error in the JQL Query: Expecting ')' or ',' but got '='. (line 1, character 46)`

I am unable to understand the ScriptRunner semantics enough to build this query - Seems powerful but too difficult to figure out how to do.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape quotes inside quotes:

`issueFunction in issuesInEpics("\"Parent Link\" = ABCD-28089 AND \"Requested Version\" = \"Release 3.3.0\"")`

Or use single quotes instead:

`issueFunction in issuesInEpics("'Parent Link' = ABCD-28089 AND 'Requested Version' = 'Release 3.3.0'")`

Comment: Thank you very much. A quick follow up question - If I have a saved query, can I use it by name i.e. like issueFunction in issuesInEpics("myNamedQuery")?

Comment: @user2789284, if you save the subquery you can refer to it this way: `issueFunction in issuesInEpics("filter = myNamedQuery")`.